# Has someone been killed or injured by being 'struck by a turtle'?

Tags: united-states, zoology

Sources, such as the [Walked Into a Lamppost? Hurt While Crocheting? Help Is on the Way](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424053111904103404576560742746021106) in the Wall Street Journal, say that there is a medicare code in NC for being 'stuck by a turtle'. I couldn't believe it. How is one 'struck by a turtle' when they move so slowly and secondly how could this be a medicare code? My friend also told me that there is a code for being 'bitten by a turtle' which seems much more plausible. Is this true?

Comment: Its part of the new IDC -10 being implemented by us health care

Comment: I submitted an edit last night that includes a notable claim (an article in the WSJ) as well as restoring the title to the asker's primary question (how does one get struck by a turtle). Not sure how to flag a question to have a hold lifted.

Comment: You should check your facts, turtles can be really fast. http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNkerUALPQY

Comment: Turtles, like anything else, accelerate at -9.8m/s^2 when falling.  You certainly could need medical treatment after an encounter with a falling turtle.

Comment: Does the original notable claim state that someone was injured by being struck by a turtle? Or merely that the code exists? I think the recent title edit moves away from the actual claim, making it harder to prove - a straw man.

Comment: The title edit moves it back to the original asker's question, as he said that the existence of the code was a _secondary_ point as he was questioning whether it was possible to be struck by a turtle in the first place. It seems that the existence of an official insurance industry code for an injury is a sufficient claim that such an injury can occur. And indeed, there are several documented instances.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the article [More On The Risk Of Death By Turtle](http://www.loweringthebar.net/2011/09/more-on-the-risk-of-death-by-turtle.html) published in Lowering the Bar, several turtle strike incidents are noted:

- The [Associated Press reported](http://articles.latimes.com/1987-05-29/news/mn-2198_1_turtle-falls-head) in 1987 that a Hong Kong man was hit in the head by a turtle that had fallen out of a high-rise apartment building. The two-pound reptilian missile "struck 36-year-old Lui Wai-kwong on the head, bruising Lui's temple and badly injuring the turtle," according to the report.
- According to [this](http://metro.co.uk/2009/07/22/girl-hit-by-plummeting-tortoise-loses-memory-289285/) story, a 12-year-old Chinese girl was hit by a "falling black object" that turned out to be a three-pound pregnant tortoise. Police believed that the animal had been thrown out of an apartment building, but had no suspects. A picture accompanying this article shows a young girl with a pretty nasty wound on the top of her head, but there's no way to confirm what caused it. This time, the animal did not survive.
- The more famous but equally unverifiable turtle impact happened in 456 B.C., when the Greek playwright Aeschylus (author of The Persians, Seven Against Thebes, and Euripides Is a Big Fat Idiot) is said to have been killed by a turtle. The [story](https://books.google.com/books?id=cEDRp8e6SMAC&lpg=PA54&dq=aeschylus%20turtle&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false) is that the turtle was dropped on him by an eagle, which presumably was hoping to crack the turtle's shell open on a rock but mistakenly hit the playwright's bald head.

The same article links out to another story on their site, [Injury Code W59.22XA: Struck By Turtle](http://www.loweringthebar.net/2011/09/injury-code-w5922xa-struck-by-turtle.html) that talks about the new code:

> I could see being bitten by a turtle, but how does one get "struck by
>   a turtle," exactly? Are these turtles being thrown or propelled, and
>   if so, how? (I'm not sure I want to know what "other contact with
>   turtle" might be.)

That article links to a now-defunct Wall Street Journal search engine for the codes, but I believe the Wall Street Journal article referenced in the article is this one: [Walked Into a Lamppost? Hurt While Crocheting? Help Is on the Way](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424053111904103404576560742746021106)

This [ICD-10 search engine](http://www.icd10data.com/) also [lists the code](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/V00-Y99/W50-W64/W59-/W59.22), categorized as:

```
-> 2015 ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Codes
    -> External causes of morbidity V00-Y99
        -> Exposure to animate mechanical forces W50-W64
            -> Contact with other nonvenomous reptiles W59
                -> Struck by turtle
```

Comment: Hmm... "Euripides Is a Big Fat Idiot"? I'm not familiar with that one!

Comment: Damn, the ICD-10 sure gets specific.

Comment: Google doesn't turn up anything about "Euripides Is a Big Fat Idiot" except in the context of being struck by turtles. I suspect that doesn't exist.

Comment: The ICD-10 looks like its full of automatically generated permutations of everything so as to cover all the bases.